# I tried to do "and" expression in the expression builder in access but it did not work

Tags: ms-access

I started to learn access two weeks ago and I am trying to learn about queries and I did not realized how i can do "and" expression in the expression builder inside of query I tried to do this(photo at the end) for like a hour but it did not work someone can help me? btw it is my first time here so i don't know how things going around here so have mercy on me thx  [my solution that did not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmW6u.png)

Comment: Edit your question to show expression as text, not image. What does "did not work" mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens?

Comment: Welcome to SO Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Always show code or queries [formated as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), not images! Solution `x>18 AND x<21` you missed to define what should be smaler than 21.

Comment: Your `IIF()` is not complete. You are missing `False` part of the function.